# How should I call a Fortran function?

Tags: fortran, fortran90, lapack, blas, fortran77

How should I call a Fortran function?

I am trying to call [DLANSY](http://linux.die.net/man/l/dlansy) but it erroneously returns 0. See the code and the program output below.

```
      SUBROUTINE COND(TYP,N,A,LDA,IPIV,WORK,LWORK,IWORK,INFO,RCOND)

      INTEGER TYP, N, LDA, IPIV(*), IWORK(*), INFO, LWORK
      DOUBLE PRECISION A(LDA,*), ANORM, RCOND, WORK(*)
      CHARACTER*1 UPLO
      EXTERNAL DLANSY, DSYTRF, DSYCON

      IF (TYP .EQ. 0) THEN 
        UPLO = 'L'
      ELSE
        UPLO = 'U'
      ENDIF

      DO I = 1, N
        DO J = 1,N 
          WRITE(*,*) I,J,A(I,J)
        END DO
      END DO

      WRITE(*,*) 'TYPE ',UPLO
      WRITE(*,*) 'N    ',N
      WRITE(*,*) 'LDA  ',LDA

      ANORM = DLANSY('1', UPLO, N, A, LDA, WORK)
C      ANORM = 10;

      WRITE(*,*) 'ANORM  ',ANORM

      END
```

And what it prints:

```
           1           1   1.0000000000000000     
           1           2   2.0000000000000000     
           1           3   3.0000000000000000     
           1           4   4.0000000000000000     
           2           1   1.0000000000000000     
           2           2   2.0000000000000000     
           2           3   3.0000000000000000     
           2           4   4.0000000000000000     
           3           1   1.0000000000000000     
           3           2   2.0000000000000000     
           3           3   3.0000000000000000     
           3           4   4.0000000000000000     
           4           1   1.0000000000000000     
           4           2   2.0000000000000000     
           4           3   3.0000000000000000     
           4           4   4.0000000000000000     
 TYPE L
 N               4
 LDA             4
 ANORM     0.0000000000000000
```

In the input arrays are of proper size.

What is going on?

Comment: Though this is irrelevant but, why exactly are you learning FORTRAN? Most universities have taken it out of their course , they don't even teach it as an educational language nowadays.

Comment: @IntermediateHacker I have to call LAPACK from a C++ code. I cannot use CLAPACK. I do not want to use Fortran but I have no other opition.

Comment: @IntermediateHacker -- an awful lot of HPC and simulation codes - including new ones - are written in Fortran, which is actually designed for scientific computing.

Comment: Found some examples on how to call it at http://www.nag.com/lapack-ex/examples/source/dsygv-ex.f and http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/clresctr/vxrx/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.cluster.essl.v5r1.essl100.doc%2Fam501_llansy.html

Comment: Also it states that `These subprograms compute the norm of matrix A, stored in upper or lower storage mode.` So maybe the storage scheme for `A` is different from an `A(n,n)` 2D matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell the compiler that DLANSY returns a double precision value, rather than real, which is what you get currently via the implicit typing rules. E.g. with a line like

```
double precision, external :: dlansy
```

Or, if for some strange reason one is limited to some ancient compiler that does not support F90:

```
DOUBLE PRECISION DLANSY
EXTERNAL DLANSY
```

Comment: OK, I have to change the corresponding line to this: `DOUBLE PRECISION A(LDA,*), ANORM, RCOND, WORK(*), DLANSY` and drop the line with `EXTERNAL ...`

Comment: @Ali: Done. FWIW, there's nothing wrong with keeping the external; it tells the compiler than it's an external symbol, not a local variable. Better yet, use implicit none, and enable all the warning options your compiler has.

Comment: Ah, -fimplicit-none, good! As for `double precision, external :: dlansy` could you add the F77 version instead?

Comment: @Ali: Actually, I was thinking of putting a "implicit none" at the beginning of your procedure. As for F77, I try to avoid writing it myself, but as you wish...

Comment: I would try to avoid Fortran altogether in the first place :) Many thanks, upvoted and accepted your answer!

Comment: By the way, how do you do the implicit none at the beginning of your procedure? Please add that to your answer too.